# cant get any input data from hid device with chrome api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, usb, google-chrome-app, hid

I am making small app that will take input data from usb device with chrome packaged app. Idea is that when i press button on usb device it will take incoming traffic, analyze it and react depending on the input.
I tried several devices and techniques from online tutorials/codes and met many problems, but after solving them i finally started to use sony playstation 3 pads. Device is connected via hid but that's all i can accomplish. Pressing any buttons doesnt make any input incoming and so far i have no idea what is the reason of that. Stackoverflow, google manuals and internet doesnt seem to have any answers on that. Here is my code:

manifest.json:

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "HID Input Analyzer",
  "version": "1.0",

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
      "persistent": true
    }
  },

  "permissions": ["hid", {
      "usbDevices": [
    { "vendorId": 1356 , "productId": 616 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('mychromeapp.html', {
    singleton: true,
    id: "Input analyzer"
  });
});
```

mychromeapp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HID Input Analyzer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <input type="text" id="mytext" />
    <script src="mychromeapp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

mychromeapp.js

```
var MY_HID_VENDOR_ID  = 0x09da; // 4660 in hexadecimal!
var MY_HID_PRODUCT_ID = 0x8090;
var DEVICE_INFO = {"vendorId": MY_HID_VENDOR_ID, "productId": MY_HID_PRODUCT_ID };

var connectionId = null;

function arrayBufferToString(array) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(array));
}

var myDevicePoll = function() {
  var size = 64;
    var i = 0;
if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);}
    chrome.hid.receive(connectionId, function(data) {
        console.log("::" + connectionId);
      if (data != null) {
            // Convert Byte into Ascii to follow the format of our device
            myText.value = arrayBufferToString(data);
            console.log('Data: ' + myText.value);
      }
    setTimeout(myDevicePoll, 0);
    });
}





function initializeHid(pollHid) {
// brackets are empty for purpose because permissions are given in manifest.json
    chrome.hid.getDevices({}, function(devices) {
        if (!devices || !devices.length) {
          console.log('device not found');
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);}
          return;
        }
        console.log('Found device with deviceId: ' + devices[0].deviceId);
        myHidDevice = devices[0].deviceId;

        // Connect to the HID device
        chrome.hid.connect(myHidDevice, function(connection) {
            console.log('Connected to the HID device with connectionId: ' + connection.connectionId);
          connectionId = connection.connectionId;

            // Poll the USB HID Interrupt pipe
            pollHid();
        });
    });
}

initializeHid(myDevicePoll);

console.log("Trying to connect to HID USB ...");


var myText = document.getElementById("mytext");
myText.value = "Ready";
```

Console log looks like this:

> Trying to connect to HID USB ...
>
> Found device with deviceId: 23
>
> Connected to the HID device with connectionId: 31

After analzying my code (especially last file) I guess that *chrome.hid.receive* function doesnt get any data from device but i dont know why. Unfortunatelly manuals of google are made very poor and lack of good examples makes it hard to code. I hope somebody can help me with solution - i am sitting with this since 3 days:(

Kalreg.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function in receive is missing a parameter. Check it out in chrome.hid page and you will notice that it is necessary a reportId parameter along with data. It worked for me, after fixing that. My problem, however, is getting new data for every new poll. That only happens if I connect it again, even if it is already connected. This problem is only for Mac and Ubuntu. In windows, mine works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Try writing the decimal equivalents of vendorID and productID from mychromeapp.js in your manifest file

Comment: Unlikely to help, since the device was found and connected.